# Python classes SOLID principles

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I'm learning OOP in Python and SOLID principles here in particular. Right now I'm curious about interface segregation, so I've come up with such classes:

```
class Info(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_info(self) -> dict:
        ...


class ProductInfo(Info):
    id: str
    name: str
    price: float
    quantity: int

    def get_info(self) -> dict:
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'price': self.price,
            'quantity': self.quantity,
        }


class CarInfo(Info):
    car_number: str
    max_speed: float
    price: float
    reg_place: str

    def get_info(self) -> dict:
        return {
            'car_number': self.car_number,
            'max_speed': self.max_speed,
            'price': self.price,
            'reg_place': self.reg_place
        }


class Car:
    car_info: Info


class Product:
    product_info: Info

    def get_unit_price(self) -> float:
        return self.product_info.get_info().get('price') * self.product_info.get_info().get('quantity')
```

**The issue:** I'd like to know if an approach of using class' attributes like in `get_unit_price` in `Product` class is correct? And if it is not right, why and how is it possible to redo it?

Comment: Seems fine, if over-engineered (which might just be a matter of oversimplification for purposes of the question). There doesn't seem to be a compelling reason for `Info` or its subclasses in place of an ordinary `dict`.

Comment: @chepner it means that's better just to move `Car`, `Product` `-Info` attributes to `Car`, `Product` classes respectively?

Comment: The thing is, it matters on how you use the methods. Since the `Product` class doesn't inherit anything, its okay. But if it inherits another class, the if the method has to be used among all classes or some classes inherited from the parent, define it in the parent. If not, and it is needed in only 1 class, define it in the class that needs it. As you asked @chepner it is recommended to do so as these classes only sort out information. If they are to be used for multiple classes then they should be individual classes but if not, they should be methods of the parent (no need of inheritance).

Comment: This question is a little opinion-based but its related to basic principles so it is okay. The answer may vary but in general follow the above rules. This means including `Car`, `Product` and `Info` characteristics into the other classes as they are not inherited by other classes. Inheritance which is not needed just makes your code more complex. Use multiple methods in each class and classes are not meant for sorting functions. They are meant for making the code connected with itself. Same with inheritance.